# Is declval<T>() the same as (*(T*)nullptr)?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Is `declval<T>()` just a replacement for the old trick of `(*(T*)NULL)` to get an instance of T in a decltype without needing to worry about T's constructor?

Here is some sample code:

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    A a;
};

typedef decltype((*(B*)nullptr).a) T1;
typedef decltype(declval<B>().a) T2;

cout << "is_same: " << is_same<T1, T2>::value << endl;
```

which prints 1 because T1 and T2 are the same type.

If declval is more than a replacement, what are the differences and where is it useful?

Comment: Does your old trick work when `T` is a reference type?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`declval()` has the advantage that if it is used in an evaluated context (i.e., odr-used) then the program is ill-formed (20.2.4p2), and a diagnostic is required to be issued (per 1.4p1).  Typically this is enforced through a `static_assert` in the library:

```
c++/4.7/type_traits: In instantiation of '[...] std::declval() [...]':
source.cpp:3:22:   required from here
c++/4.7/type_traits:1776:7: error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
```

`declval` also works on reference types:

```
using S = int &;
using T = decltype(std::declval<S>());
using U = decltype(*(S *)nullptr);  // fails
```

Where the type is *not* a reference type, `declval` will give an rvalue type where `nullptr` gives an lvalue.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your first point:  Using declval outside of a decltype will cause a compile error where using (\*(T\*)NULL) in the same place would cause no complaints at compile time and a segfault at runtime.  decltype is clearly better.

Comment: @walrii that's right, except that a segfault at runtime is not guaranteed.

Comment: Great answer ! Lovely !

Comment: Note that this is not always strictly an advantage; for instance, if for some reason you need to know the address offset of a class-member, [the casting-a-literal trick will allow you to determine this without constructing an actual class object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36165639/1858225), but `declval` will not.

Comment: @Kyle Strand that trick has undefined behavior, so it's immaterial whether or not you could achieve the same result with declval; in fact, you could if you can guarantee that the call to declval will not be odr-used. To find the offset of a class member you should be using offsetof anyway.

Comment: @ecatmur As far as I know, there's no standard way to get the offset for a non-POD or non-standard-layout type, which is probably why AOSP uses the code they do even though it's technically UB.

Comment: Is there a more confusing message than " error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!"? The average programmer will complain "why does it exist if I can't use it". They probably mean "must not be odr-used", or should completely change that message IMO.

Answer (score 8):

No, `declval<T>()` is not the same as `(*(T*)nullptr)`. And `decltype(expr.bar)` is not the same as `decltype((expr.bar))`.

The former comparison compares expressions. The latter use of `decltype` inspects the expression and the former use of `decltype` inspects the declared type of `expr.bar`. So you have to paren your uses of the `decltype` operand to make a useful comparison of the types and you will find they are different.

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    A a;
};

// E1: B().a 
// E2: declval<A>().a
// E3: (*(B*)0).a
// E4: ((B&&)(*(B*)0)).a
```

In these 4 expressions, all expressions have type `A`. `E1` is a prvalue (in C++14 it is an xvalue. Some compilers probably will treat it as an xvalue even in their C++11 mode), `E2` is an xvalue. `E3` is an lvalue and `E4` is an xvalue again.

```
// T1: decltype((*(B*)0).a)
// T2: decltype(((*(B*)0).a))
```

In these two types, the first decltype gives the type of the member named by the expression. The member has type `A`, so `T1` is `A`. The second decltype yields the type of the expression, modified by `&` if the expression is an lvalue and modified by `&&` if the expression is an xvalue. The expression is an lvalue, so `T2` is `A&`.

Comment: Appreciate if you would go more about why `B().a` is a prvalue I thought it's an xvalue and  i also thought `E2` should be `declval<B>().a`.

Comment: @FallingFromBed B().a is an xvalue since only c++14. I will add a note

Comment: Johannes Schaub - litb , Good Thanks!