# How does std::declval<T>() work?

Tags: c++, c++11, declval, reference-collapsing

I am trying to understand how `std::declval<T>()` works. I know how to use it, and know what it does, mainly allows you to use `decltype` without constructing the object, like

```
decltype(std::declval<Foo>().some_func()) my_type; // no construction of Foo
```

I know from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) that `std::declval<Foo>` "adds" a rvalue reference to `Foo`, which due to reference collapsing rules ends up being either a rvalue reference or a lvalue reference. My question is why the constructor of `Foo` is not called? How can one implement a "toy" version of `std::declval<T>` without constructing the template parameter?

PS: [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14657092/3093378) it is not the same as the old trick

```
(*(T*)(nullptr))
```

Comment: From the same page: "Note that because no definition exists for declval, it can only be used in unevaluated contexts; it is an error to evaluate an expression that contains this function."

Comment: @remyabel yes, I saw that, I just don't know how to "build" my own `declval`

Comment: `template< class T >
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();` is literally all you need. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a8d4e5cfa60355f)

Comment: Take a look at [Is there a reason declval returns add_rvalue_reference instead of add_lvalue_reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303250/is-there-a-reason-declval-returns-add-rvalue-reference-instead-of-add-lvalue-ref) and [Why does std::declval add a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707441/why-does-stddeclval-add-a-reference)

Comment: @remyabel thanks, I understand most of it, the only thing that escapes me is why can we use the `.` operator to select a function from a rvalue reference to an object without constructing the object, like `std::declval<Foo>().f()` I know that `std::declval<Foo>()` is of type `Foo&&`, but didn't know you can "access" it's member function via the `.` operator, as you didn't construct the object. I thought one should have use the scope operator `::`

Comment: @vsoftco: You're calling a non-static member function of an object. (well, you would be if the expression was evaluated) And for calling a non-static member function, you use a dot. Why would you expect that to be different in this case? Specifically, why would you expect the scope operator to be used?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think I find it a bit strange as you are not calling a function of a *constructed* object, but are just pretending to.

Comment: @vsoftco take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749349/finding-offset-of-a-structure-element-in-c, i definitely read the answer `printf("%p\n", (void*)(&((struct s *)NULL)->i));` in some real code. and for me, `std::declval<Foo>().f()` is a similar usage: extract meta information other than calling the function/access the variable

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically, in a `sizeof` or `decltype` expression you can call functions that aren't implemented anywhere (they need to be declared, not implemented).

E.g.

```
class Silly { private: Silly( Silly const& ) = delete; };

auto foo() -> Silly&&;

auto main() -> int
{
    sizeof( foo() );
}
```

The linker should not complain about that.

Comment: Ahh, ok, now it makes sense why "adding a rvalue reference" does the trick. For some reason I didn't know you can use `decltype` on just declared functions. The only thing I'm still a bit puzzled is why can you call `.f()` in `declval<Foo>().f()`, I would have thought you need something like `declval<Foo>()::f()`

Comment: @vsoft in an unevaluated context, all that matters are types.  You don't need the instance to use the instance: you just need to pretend.  What, after all, is the sound of one hand falling in the forest if there are two trolly tracks?

Comment: I still don't get it. Wouldn't `auto foo() -> Silly;` work just as well? Or `Silly&`? Why r-value reference is needed here?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It's useful where you may not know the return type of `Foo::foo()` in advance and want to declare your type with the same type as the one returned by `Foo::foo()`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe like above, when you do not know the type T at hand in template contexts but need to call a function of that type. You may not write T().foo(), because you can't make assumptions that T has default (or any other) constructor. Hence you need to call function through reference. I'm not sure exactly why rvalue reference is selected there.

Comment: Does this really ansewr the question?

Comment: @Wormer, I am a year late, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20303350/1116098) might answer why an rvalue reference is used in `declval()`.