# How does std::declval work?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can somebody explain how does std::declval work?
I've found this implementation inside gcc headers/type_traits (lines 2248-2262), which is (cleared up a bit to improve readability):

```
template<typename _Tp>
struct __declval_protector
{
    static const bool __stop = false;
    static typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type __delegate();
};

template<typename _Tp>
typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type
declval ()
{
    static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop, "declval() must not be used!");
    return __declval_protector<_Tp>::__delegate();
}
```

I don't understand the part `return __declval_protector<_Tp>::__delegate()`, does it call the *default initializer* for an Rvalue reference of type *T*?
Also i don't understand why the `static_assert` is not called every time I call `declval`, since `__stop` is always false (And how can it distinguish between unevaluated contexts and evaluated ones?).

**EDIT:**
From what I understand now, all this stuff is equivalent to:

```
template<typenam _Tp>
struct __declval_protector
{
    const bool __stop = false;
};

template<typename _Tp>
typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type
mydeclval ()
{
    static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop, "declval() must not be used!");
}
```

But of course the compiler will issue that we do not return anything.

Comment: `__delegate` is a function. It's just like `int f();`, and the you say `f()`.

Comment: @vsoftco I have reopened the question as I am pretty sure it is not a duplicate. The question has a misleading title but it targets declval protector usage, not declval principles of work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does std::declval<T>() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532781/how-does-stddeclvalt-work)

Answer (score 18):

> I don't understand why the static_assert is not called every time I call declval, since __stop is always false

Your premise is wrong. The static assert *is* indeed called every time you call `declval`. The trick is that *you must never call `declval`*. It must only be used in unevaluated contexts. That's why the static assertion is there.

Comment: And what's the purpose of the return statement?

Comment: @MattiaF.: To make the function well-formed and avoid warnings perhaps? Note that the function isn't defined, by the way.

Comment: I am surprised gcc actually has this implementation. I'd expect it to have declaration only. Are they trying to be nice to users? :)

Comment: Funny thing is that this template is ill-formed since it has no valid specialization. But it's okay since it occurs inside the implementation ;)

Comment: @Brian Hmm, there can hypothetically be a specialization of `__declval_protector` later that has a true `__stop`, no?

Comment: @T.C. Oh yeah, that could be the case... I just realized I'm not entirely sure how that rule is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: @T.C. It would be a lot simpler if we could just allow `static_assert(false, ...)` in these cases.

Comment: @Mattia F. If a static_assert isn't dependent on a template parameter, it fires whether the template is instantiated or not.

Comment: @T.C.: I think It's also UB if your program defines specializations that are not visible at the time of instantiation, isn't it?

Comment: @KerrekSB Time of instantiation or time of definition? Of course this triggers an error at instantiation time when there turns out to be no such specialization after all.

Comment: @T.C.: Hm, that's true. I was trying to address the point of the template being ill-formed, but I'm not sure whether it really matters.