# How to capture a type of return value of a function returning a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Given this code:

```
template <class Func> class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    /** @param func function object to be executed in dtor
    */
    explicit ScopeGuard( Func && func ) : m_func( std::move(func) ) {}

    ~ScopeGuard()
    {
        if (m_bDismissed)
            return;
        m_func();
    }

    /** Dismisses the scope guard, i.e. the function won't
        be executed.
    */
    void dismiss() { m_bDismissed = true; }

private:
    // noncopyable until we have good reasons...
    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
    ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;

    Func m_func;
    bool m_bDismissed = false;
};

// Get functor for cleanup to use in FlagRestorationGuard
auto GetFlagRestorationGuard(bool& i_flagRef)
{
    return [&i_flagRef, resetVal = i_flagRef] { i_flagRef = resetVal; };
}

class FlagRestorationGuard : public ScopeGuard<decltype(GetFlagRestorationGuard(*(new bool)))>
{
public:
    FlagRestorationGuard( bool& i_flagRef, bool i_temporaryValue )
        : ScopeGuard(GetFlagRestorationGuard(i_flagRef))
    {
        i_flagRef = i_temporaryValue;
    }
};
```

I get the following error building with Apple Clang for `GetFlagRestorationGuard(*(new bool))`:

> error: expression with side effects has no effect in an unevaluated context [-Werror,-Wunevaluated-expression]

Note that this code builds and works fine with MSVC 2017.
Of course, it's possible to re-write it all to use a struct with `operator()()` instead of lambda and a function returning it, but I wonder if there is a nice way to use lambda like this?

[Reference](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/#/c/71346/6/include/comphelper/flagguard.hxx) for the actual code:

[Reference](https://ci.libreoffice.org/job/gerrit_mac/31591/consoleFull#-371592627d107d11c-eea5-4209-baa1-fcfb59f7f8a6) to build failure:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a warning you're seeing; not an error.  It's warning you that the side-effect of `new bool` (allocating memory) will not happen because it's in an unevaluated context.

To get rid of the warning, instead of using `*(new bool)` as the placeholder argument in your `decltype` expression, use `std::declval<bool&>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::declval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532781/how-does-stddeclvalt-work) with an lvalue referrence to `bool`:

```
class FlagRestorationGuard :
    public ScopeGuard<decltype(GetFlagRestorationGuard(std::declval<bool&>()))>
{
    ...
};
```