# "-Werror=subobject-linkage" for lambda as a template parameter in header: what is the reason to reject this?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

A follow-up for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878790/how-to-capture-a-type-of-return-value-of-a-function-returning-a-lambda).

Given this code in `header.hxx`:

```
template <class Func> class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    /** @param func function object to be executed in dtor
    */
    explicit ScopeGuard( Func && func ) : m_func( std::move(func) ) {}

    ~ScopeGuard()
    {
        if (m_bDismissed)
            return;
        m_func();
    }

    /** Dismisses the scope guard, i.e. the function won't
        be executed.
    */
    void dismiss() { m_bDismissed = true; }

private:
    // noncopyable until we have good reasons...
    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
    ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;

    Func m_func;
    bool m_bDismissed = false;
};

// Get functor for cleanup to use in FlagRestorationGuard
auto GetFlagRestorationGuard(bool& i_flagRef)
{
    return [&i_flagRef, resetVal = i_flagRef] { i_flagRef = resetVal; };
}

class FlagRestorationGuard : public ScopeGuard<decltype(GetFlagRestorationGuard(std::declval<bool&>()))>
{
public:
    FlagRestorationGuard( bool& i_flagRef, bool i_temporaryValue )
        : ScopeGuard(GetFlagRestorationGuard(i_flagRef))
    {
        i_flagRef = i_temporaryValue;
    }
};
```

and this code in `file.cxx`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include "header.hxx"

void foo()
{
    bool bFlag = false;
    {
        // Test that comphelper::FlagRestorationGuard properly sets and resets the flag
        comphelper::FlagRestorationGuard aGuard(bFlag, true);
        assert(bFlag);
    }
    assert(!bFlag);
}
```

produces this error:

```
error: ‘comphelper::FlagRestorationGuard’ has a field ‘comphelper::FlagRestorationGuard::<anonymous>’ whose type uses the anonymous namespace [-Werror=subobject-linkage]
     class FlagRestorationGuard
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I see how the lambda is of course unnamed object, using an implicit unnamed namespace; but how is this relevant in this case? Why should this diagnostic block anything here?

[Reference](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/#/c/71416/2/include/comphelper/flagguard.hxx) to the code.

[Reference](https://ci.libreoffice.org/job/gerrit_linux_gcc_release/30920/consoleFull#1745523892d107d11c-eea5-4209-baa1-fcfb59f7f8a6) to error.

Comment: Per https://github.com/NVIDIA/stdexec/issues/1143#issuecomment-1937482532, seems like a bug of gcc-14